# Web service vs Web API (What's the real difference)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-services, asp.net-core-webapi

Can someone explain me the difference between Web services & web API? I have gone through so many blogs but all of them seems to be using the same bookish knowledge. What's the actual difference between them in real terms?

Comment: As far as you’re concerned, they’re the same thing. Though “Web API” may refer to “ASP.NET Core Web API” specifically, while “Web Service” is a very general term that also encompasses _great old ones_ (er… I mean Legacy) tech like SOAP, XML-RPC, etc.

Comment: Please check this:->   https://www.guru99.com/api-vs-web-service-difference.html

Comment: Thanks @Dai , I have read it somewhere that web service is a general term but then my doubt was what problems were there in web service that people had to move to web API? And also when to use what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) explained the zest and I completely agree with him. In addition, I would like to provide you some real-life difference besides.

**Web Service:**

As `Web Service` basically, used `WSDL` which used to communicate with `SOAP` or `XML` base service. However, the main challenge in `Web Service` was to handle cross-platform request. We used to add service reference as following way: While developped Web Services.

[image]

[image]

**Web API:**

Considering these drawbacks, Microsoft, latter on developed the `Web API` more specifically, `Asp.net Web API` which provide the robust functionality for cross platform development using REST pattern mostly used `Json` data. It doesn’t mean that `web service` cannot do that, but not robust as `Web API` now a days. Unlike, web service we don’t need to go through any integration hassle as above which we can directly develop using asp.net core project and can open the route to call from anywhere.For instance below example:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/VehicleFilter")]
    public class VehicleFilterController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;


        public VehicleFilterController(IWebHostEnvironment environment, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _environment = environment;
            _context = context;
        }
       
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllFilter()
        {

           string VehicleName = "Hatchback";
           var sqlCommand = $"EXEC GetVehicleByTile {VehicleName}";
           var vehicleFilterValues = await _context.VehicleFilter.FromSqlRaw(sqlCommand).ToListAsync();
           return Ok(vehicleFilterValues);
        }


    }
```

To summarize, `Web API` provides more flexibility and robustness and of course its lightweight while writing any new method. Where `web service` leads to some demerits to the developer.

Comment: Thanks Farid for the explanation. So if I understood correctly, the drawbacks of web services were -: 1) It could not handle cross platform request (means a web service built on Windows machine will NOT be able to connect with web services built on Linux machines (or) is it like a .Net web service will not be able to connect to a Java web service? ).     2) web services only communicate with XML data using Soap protocol, Whereas in API we can communicate with json, XML etc...am I right? 3) One doubt, can a web service interact with a web API?

Comment: To answer first question, at that time yes linux wasn't supported, secondly, it can also `Json` however, there is some hassle not easy as `Web API`. Finally, yes we can connect `WebService` to `Web API` For sure. using connected service but this practice doesn't seen frequently.